# MySQL: List databases with tables

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to list all my databases with tables in a single command?

Expectation:

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES, TABLES;

    DB1 table1
        table2
    DB2 table1
        table2
        table3
        table4
        table5
    DB3 table1
        table2
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the information stored in **[`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html)**:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
ORDER BY table_schema, table_name;
```

`table_schema` is the database name.

To show also the databases without any tables:

```
SELECT s.schema_name, t.table_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.schemata AS s 
  LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables AS t 
    ON t.table_schema = s.schema_name 
-- optional, to hide system databases and tables
-- WHERE s.schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema')
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name ;
```

Documentation links: [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html),  [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.schemata`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/schemata-table.html)

Answer (score 3):

## QUERY #1 (Separate Columns)

```
SET @db = '';
SELECT db,tb FROM
(SELECT @tb := IF(@db=table_schema,table_name,'') tb,
IF(@db=table_schema,'',table_schema) db,
(@db := table_schema) unused FROM information_schema.tables) A;
```

## QUERY #2 (One Column)

```
SET @db = '';
SELECT CONCAT(db,'  ',tb) DBTB FROM
(SELECT @tb := IF(@db=table_schema,table_name,'') tb,
IF(@db=table_schema,'',table_schema) db,
(@db := table_schema) unused FROM information_schema.tables) A;
```

## QUERY #3 (DB on First Table, Separate Columns)

```
SET @db = '';
SELECT db,tb FROM
(SELECT IF(@db=table_schema,'',table_schema) db,
table_schema tb,(@db := table_schema) unused FROM information_schema.tables) A;
```

## QUERY #4 (DB on First Table, One Column)

```
SET @db = '';
SELECT CONCAT(RPAD(db,20,' '),tb) dbtb FROM
(SELECT IF(@db=table_schema,'',table_schema) db,
table_schema tb,(@db := table_schema) unused FROM information_schema.tables) A;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in the Query #1 for any reason in each DB is missing the first table. How can I solve it?

Comment: Both queries were designed to make DB disappear when displaying a table name and appear when changing databases. I did it this way to match the output you asked for in the question.

Comment: So there's no chance to make `table 1` of each DB appear using this queries?

Comment: Please post the exact output format in the question

Comment: Added `QUERY #3`

Comment: Query #3 is not working, When running it I got
DB1    DAB1
       DBA1
DB2    DB2
       DB2
       DB2
       DB2
       DB2
DB3    DB3
       DB3

Comment: Query #3 works. I just tried it.

Comment: I also added `QUERY #4`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21471/discussion-between-tachomi-and-rolandomysqldba).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to exclude MySQL internal databases,

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ( 'information_schema', 'performance_schema', 'mysql' );
```

No need to add 'ORDER BY'

Comment: This answer is the same as @Phil one but only adding the condition and telling that the ̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣`ORDER BY` clause is not necessary, I think this could be better as a comment to that answer. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @tachomi, I joined stack exchange today while it needs 50 reputation to add comment. I dont know if this was the reason for downvote

Comment: I didn't downvote you buddy :S